# Will a account get locked while logging in FTP mode to a remote server whose password has already expired in UNIX

Tags: users, ftp

I have a  FTP user id to a remote server, the password for which has expired.The account is getting locked if connection is being made in FTP mode to the server with the old(expired) password. Is  this possible?

Comment: That depends on your FTP server and how it's configured. Many systems use [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules); if yours does, unless the FTP service has been configured differently from others, it will have the same expiration and locking rules. What FTP server are you using, and how is it configured?